# copy a folder in resource

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa which needs to copy a folder added to resource to other location in System/library .How can i specify the source and destination path.Looking for a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd use `NSFileManager` which has really nice convenient methods. There is method like

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

And here's the description of it from apple docs:

`Copies the directory or file specified in a given path to a different location in the file system identified by another path.`

Comment: This won't work because /System is a privileged location. You would need to run the copy in a separate tool which has been elevated to administrator privileges. An installer as suggested by Peter Hosey is the right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

> I am developing an application in cocoa which needs to copy a folder added to resource to other location in System/library .

1. It sounds like you're writing an installer. [Use PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution/); don't write your own custom installer. There are a thousand edge cases that Installer already handles and your custom installer will not.
2. Do you *really* need to install this file in /System? The only kind of thing that absolutely needs to be there is a driver. If what you're installing is anything else, the answer is no, and you should not install it to /System.