# How to Copy Folder to System folder in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, copy, file-permissions

I am developing an application in cocoa which needs to copy a set of files to the system folder. When copying files to system folder I am getting a "Permission denied " error message . How can I resolve this problem.

Please any one help me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apple is very clear that the System folder is off limits to developers and that they reserve the right to change anything and everything stored there. That's why they provide folders in the Library folder to add the kinds of things you'd be tempted to put in System. If you can give us an idea of what files you need to copy, we can tell you where the best place would be to put them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X uses a system of authorization that prevent application to copy files in system locations without warning. That's why you have to enter your credentials when installing a framework for example.

If you want to perform privileged operations in your application, I suggest you to read the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) and especially the **Scenarios** chapter: it will help you to decide how to do the file copy.

Comment: The shared link is broken

Comment: I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be necessary to put anything in /System, and it's probably not a good idea anyway, as it could get wiped out by a system update. My guess is that whatever you're looking to do should be possible by some other means, e.g. using /Library or ~/Library.

Comment: I can think of two things that, AFAIK, can only work in /System: Device drivers and file-system drivers. Even kernel extensions (if they're application-specific, not device drivers) can work outside of /System; you'd just need to load them on demand by running kextload.

Answer (score 1):

Use PackageMaker to make a proper Installer package, like I suggested on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160173/copy-a-folder-in-resource).